# Testing for significant difference in number of -1s and 1s in given array?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, bootstrap

Suppose I have an array containing -1s, 0s, and 1s, e.g. [-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0]. I would like to test whether there is a significant difference in the number of -1s and 1s (imagine that this array is quite large).

Currently, I simulating samples from the null distribution (that the number of 1s is the same as the number of 0s) by taking the observed array and randomly flipping a -1 or 1 with 0.5 probability (Resulting in an array with 50/50 1s and -1s regardless of the initial observed distribution (and do this numerous times to get multiple samples). However, this leaves the number of 0s constant in each sample.

Is there a better method? For instance, would it be better to first randomly sample with replacement from this array AND THEN flip randomly, resulting in approximately 50/50 1s and -1s but a different amount of 0s every time? If so why?

Comment: Is it possible that the sequence could exhibit serial correlation, or do you know (or assume) each outcome is independent of all others?

Comment: Assume each is independent (no serial correlation)

Comment: Then--perhaps surprisingly--the zeros do not matter.  I recall this being discussed on this site some half dozen years ago, but I can't advise you concerning what search terms to look for.